# Find a particular branch when working on multiple submodules

Tags: git

I am working on a project that consists of multiple submodules. Let's say 20 submodules. Now a particular ticket requires some changes in `module_3, and module_4, and module_7`. So I create a branch for that ticket (say `branch_ticket_x`) on `module_3, and module_4, and module_7`, did my changes and commit the code (have not pushed it yet). 
At that particular moment my Manager came and assigned me another xyz task on another project. Unfortunately that task took long time. And when I came back to my old project I forgot the modules on which I was previously working, but I know that I created the branch with `branch_ticket_x` name. So is there any way or git command, I can find out on which modules I was working before.

If this is a duplicate question, please give me the link to solution.

Comment: Is this a normal way to work with submodules? Feels crazy. I am wondering is it better to just use a new branch when a task effect several submodules, while some other submodule need the old version of these submodules to be changed.

Comment: Well I can not debate on that, but let's assume that situation is something like described above. Then what's the solution ?

Comment: `Use multiple branch for different version of code, and use tag to mark a milestone, so that you can quickly refer to it anytime. When you need to interact with others, use the master as the join point. Your other branch are only visible to yourself as internal work.` This is mainly how I worked,

Comment: If you were working on `branch_ticket_X`, just switch to it, and compare it (via `git diff`) with some branch/tag (if you remember any) that before you did the long term task, so that to see what you changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git submodule -q foreach '
        git rev-parse -q --verify branch_ticket_x >&- && echo $name || true'
```

You could also `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` instead of the `echo $name` if using the variable doesn't suit.

Comment: Getting "Stopping at <submodule_name>'; script returned non-zero status."

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [`ls-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html):

```
git ls-tree <commit-SHA>
```

Comment: I am getting fatal: Not a valid object name <branch_name>

Comment: @gmuhammad try commit-SHA

Comment: Don't you think each branch in each submodule must have different hash ?

Answer (score 0):

If the path/filenames are distinct you can

```
$ git log --name-only branch_ticket_x
```

That will list the files you touched as part of your commit(s)

Comment: Each submodule is a different directory. For example /project is root directory, and submodules are /project/module_1, /project/module_2 ...
So in this case if I run above command it gives me error. fatal: ambiguous argument <branch_name>